# Why Send Email Plugin is not working?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have created a plugin (using Developer's tool kit) which will send a mail to `Participants`, which is converted `Contacts`, whenever a `Participants` is created. 
But this plugin is not Working. When I was trying to debug it this following message came in plugin registration tool(SDK)

```
Profiler> Plug-in AppDomain Created
Profiler> Parsed Profiler File Successfully.
Profiler> Constructor Execution Started: XXXXXXXX
Profiler> Constructor Execution Completed Successfully (Duration = 8ms).
Profiler> Profiler Execution Started: XXXXXXXXXXX
Plug-in> Entered CRMEmailToParticipantsPackage.EmailPlugins.PostParticipantCreate.Execute(), 
Plug-in> Exiting CRMEmailToParticipantsPackage.EmailPlugins.PostParticipantCreate.Execute(),
Profiler> Profiler Execution Completed Successfully (Duration = 57ms).
Profiler> Profiler AppDomain Unloaded
```

. Pipeline Stage is Pre-Validation on Create Message. 
And this is my Code:

```cs
protected void ExecutePostParticipantCreate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
    if (localContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
    }

    // TODO: Implement your custom Plug-in business logic.

    IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
    IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
        context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
    {
        try
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            if (entity.LogicalName == "new_participant")
            {
                Guid Contact_id = ((EntityReference)entity.Attributes["new_participantscontact"]).Id;


                Guid trip_Id = ((EntityReference)entity.Attributes["new_tripparticipants"]).Id;

                ColumnSet col1 = new ColumnSet("new_name", "new_date", "new_destination");
                Entity trip = service.Retrieve("new_trip", trip_Id, col1);
                var Trip_name = trip.Attributes["new_name"];
                var Trip_date = trip.Attributes["new_date"];
                var Trip_destination = trip.Attributes["new_destination"];
                string emailBody = "Hi, your " + Trip_name.ToString() + "is booked on : " + Trip_date.ToString() + "; Destination : " + Trip_destination.ToString();
                Guid _userId = context.UserId;

                ActivityParty fromParty = new ActivityParty
                {
                    PartyId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, _userId)
                };


                ActivityParty toParty = new ActivityParty
                {
                    PartyId = new EntityReference("new_participantscontact", Contact_id)
                };

               Email email = new Email
                    {
                    To = new ActivityParty[] { toParty },
                    From = new ActivityParty[] { fromParty },
                    Subject =Trip_name.ToString()+ "  :Trip Details",
                    Description = emailBody,
                    DirectionCode = true
                    };

                Guid emailID = service.Create(email);

               SendEmailRequest req = new SendEmailRequest();
               req.EmailId = emailID;
               req.TrackingToken = "";
               req.IssueSend = true;

               SendEmailResponse res = (SendEmailResponse)service.Execute(req);
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {

            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Have I done any thing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the plugin is not firing?

Comment: Sry its firing, I was profiling this plugin using SDK pluginregistration tool,while debugging nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

i think the first thing is discover if your plugin is fired or not. Try [debug](http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.ca/2011/11/how-to-debug-crm-2011-online-plugin.html) or use [ITracingService](http://mscrmtech.com/2010112682/mscrm-2011-useful-itracingservice-addiion-when-creating-plugin-assemblies) to know that. If you discover that is your plugin isn't fired the code is unnecessary. Be careful that the deploy of a plugin in CRM Online has a limitation of running just in sandbox mode. Try see this [step-by-step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515.aspx) deploy of a plugin in CRM Online.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to debug using the steps listed here: http://microsoftcrmworld.blogspot.com/2013/01/debug-plugins-on-your-local-pc-without.html ?

If not, you can add some localContext.trace() calls and then throw an exception at the very end of your execute method. Download and view the log file to see the outputs from localContext.trace(). This will give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: It looks ok, is the email entity getting created but not being sent?

Comment: If it's being created but not sent then it is likely an issue with the email router. Are you accessing CRM with the web client or the Outlook client?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine... 
I observed that you are sending mail to a custom entity... 
Have you enabled "Sending Email" option during customization?

[Check this link for enabling it](http://www.avanadeblog.com/xrm/2010/11/crm-2011-feature-of-the-week-11222010-new-entity-creation-flexibility.html)